# Joda time formatter odd string pattern

Tags: jodatime

I'm trying to format date strings that are coming through like this:

```
Tue, 01 Sep, 00:11
Tue, 01 Sep, 00:13
Tue, 01 Sep, 00:27
```

And having some trouble. Can anyone suggest a format pattern using DateTimeFormat.forPattern to convert these to DateTime objects? Note that the year can be inferred from the current year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
        String dateToParse = "Tue, 01 Sep, 00:27";
        DateTime dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE, dd MMM, HH:mm YYYY" ).parseDateTime( dateToParse + " " + DateTime.now().getYear()  );
        System.out.println( dt );
```

Comment: That way of grabbing the year is what I was missing. Thank you, worked great

Comment: If you don't mind please accept the answer :) Thanks.